# How to inject contentResolver with Koin

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, koin, koin-scope

I'm trying to inject a contentProvider with koin in my datasource class, but I can't find any approach to can do it.

This is my dataSource

```
class MyDataSource(private val application: Application, private val contentProvider: ContentResolver) : MyRepository {...}
```

and my module of koin

```
single<MyRepository> {
        MyDataSource(get(), get())
    }
```

And I'm getting this error:

Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for 'android.content.ContentResolver' has been found. Check your module definitions.

Comment: You would have to create an instance of your content provider inside your module.. Similar to how you are trying to create an instance of your data source class

Comment: Did you find a soultion? facing the same problem here

Answer (score 0):

Tell Koin how to obtain a `ContentResolver`. Assuming you intialize your module in your custom `Application` (say `MyApplication`) class:

```
private val module = module {

    single { this@MyApplication.contentResolver } // tell Koin this is your ContentResolver

    single<MyRepository> {
        MyDataSource(get(), get()) // now Koin knows how to get the content resolver here
    }
}
```

Comment: Unable to get  this@MyApplivation. Its always resorting to this@module

Answer (score -1):

Call `androidContext()` extension function that holds reference to `ContentResolver`:

```
val module = module {
  // ...

  single<ContentResolver> { androidContext().contentResolver }

  single<MyRepository> {
        MyDataSource(get(), get())
    }
  // ...
}
```